# How can I access the MCP3008 ADC chip with linux spidev?

Tags: adc, integrated-circuit, spi, linux

There is quite a bit of bit-banging sources to work with this 10-bit resolution chip, but I'd like to know if this kind of chips are natively supported by Linux.

Primarily I'd like this to be in C, but I also accept answers in other language if written without some funky language-specific libraries.

Answer (score 1):

It's got a SPI based interface, correct?  If so, then you should be able to just write a userspace driver to interface with the chip.  Did you look at [Interfacing an SPI ADC (MCP3008) chip to the Raspberry Pi using C++ (spidev)](http://hertaville.com/2013/07/24/interfacing-an-spi-adc-mcp3008-chip-to-the-raspberry-pi-using-c/)?

If your hardware has SPI then your kernel should have a SPI driver loaded, and `/dev/spidev*` should be populated.

Comment: The hardware is Raspberry Pi.